# How to create india map chart using Hightcharts?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, highcharts

I want to generate reports in Graph. Suppose I want to see my sales in all over india. I want to see in india map chart. So I would be able to see this state sales is this much and so on. I have generated bar chart, pie chart and line chart using Hight Charts. But now I want to generate map chart. But I am not getting how to go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HighCharts has some pre-alpha proof of concepts on doing heat maps (or choropleth). See this post [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/971471-create-highmaps-mapping-library-like-ammap-but-w). It is not in main released version.

Now, you could use any number of other JS libraries to do this. There are essentially 3 steps:

1. Get mapping data as SVG (or some other format). These are the
   shapefiles used to draw the outlines of the geographic features you
   want.
2. In these mapping shapefiles there is an ID associated that is
   unique to it. Now assign your data values to this ID/area.
3. Using [D3](http://d3js.org/), [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), etc draw the shapefiles and link the data. If you have large amounts of cash laying around you can give it to ESRI to purchase [ESRI ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis).